# Missing Referenced Assemblies Folder for .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

It seems that starting with .NET 3.0, Microsoft moved some common assemblies to

`C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\xxx`

in order to support their effort to split out the CLR 2.0 and CLR 4.0 GACs (having also added

`C:\%windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly`).

However, while I have both

`C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\xxx`

and

`C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0`

on my development machine, the latter does not exist on a server where I just installed .NET 4.0.  A WCF project being deployed there references some common DLLs from this folder and cannot find them.

What am I doing wrong?  Should I change these references to the new 4.0 GAC explicitly?  Why does this folder not exist on the server?

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't just install a 32bit .net 4.0 on a 64bit machine and the reference assemblies folder has ended up in `Program files(x86)`?

Comment: @KlausByskovHoffmann the server is 32 bit as well, so no `Program files(x86)` folder.  Good suggestion though!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Reference Assemblies folder is used with Visual Studio. While the actual deployed application will use the GAC in c:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Assembly. I am assuming you didn't install Visual Studio on your server, therefore you wouldn't have the Reference Assemblies Folder.

If you hosting WCF on the server, you need to ensure you installed .NET 4.0 Full Framework and not just the client framework.

Comment: Accepted the answer because it properly explains the GAC/Reference Assemblies set up in .NET 4.0.  However, in my case, it turned out that I was missing some non-Framework dll's on the server and they were the root cause of my troubles.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: One thing to note is that Reference Assemblies contents come with VS *as well as several SDKs, and there are even separate downloads from Microsoft*.

Comment: @arviman Microsoft has a page, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/hh487283.aspx

Comment: @LexLi - thanks, but i ended up pointing to the .net framework dll instead of Reference Assemblies

Comment: You should always point to reference assemblies. More background https://blog.lextudio.com/the-rough-history-of-referenced-assemblies-7d752d92c18c