# Which files are stored in Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, assemblies

I'd like to know which kind of files are stored in

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\

Are those files meant for WPF/Silverlight?

And which installer install the files in that folder?

I'd like to know this because we have developed a winforms application with custom WPF controls. When we deploy the application on a bare system, the application crashes when these controls are used...

Comment: MSDN has a very good description of what is included and not in the Client Profile: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx

Comment: @M.Babcock Thanks, but what do I have to do to install the v4.0 folder?

Comment: There is a separate install for the Client Profile: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24872

Comment: @M.Babcock I've installed .Net Framework 4 and I still don't have the 4.0 folder. In the Software list I see MS .NET Framework 4 Client profile and MS .NET Framework 4 Extended...

Comment: According to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2009/10/19/what-s-new-in-net-framework-4-client-profile-beta-2.aspx) article the client profile assemblies should be installing to the directory you mention.

Comment: It is very strange that you would need to worry about the location of the folder. What does the exception message say? Does it indicate that the controls are missing?

Comment: @M.Babcock Thanks for the the link. I will read it and hopefully it brings me further.

Comment: @CodyGray Well, I don't get an exception. The application stops working and when I view event viewer it says 'App crash'

Comment: Have you tried to compile application and set "Copy" Dll = true in your properties-references?

Comment: Did you see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153048/missing-referenced-assemblies-folder-for-net-4-0

Answer (score 0):

1. **WPF** is part of the .NET Framework since version 3.0
2. **Silverlight** is different from WPF and has a [separate SDK download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=7335)
3. Files located under *Reference Assemblies* folder, are usually installed by Visual studio when installing SDK and [(in your case), are part of the **Windows 7 and .NET 4 Framework SDK**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279).
4. Winforms and WPF are quite different technologies. In short, Winforms are wrappers above Windows C++ MFC library and WPF are wrappers above DirectX library.
5. You should check [the difference between Client profile and Full Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759228/differences-between-microsoft-net-4-0-full-framework-and-client-profile) because most of the time, your application should target the Client profile and in only few scenario, it should target the Full Framework. By the way, if you're using the **.NET Framework 4.5 or above**, **Client profile has been discontinued**. It simplifies the deployment process.
6. Check in the references properties in your C# project that the `Copy Local` is set to `True`. It will copy the referenced library in the output directory of the project.