# Server 2k3 Missing Assemblies for .NET 4

Tags: .net, iis-6

I've been building a site for work on my Windows 7 box and the app will be deployed to a 2k3 machine.  I FINALLY got it working where the site will load with the extensionless urls.  Now my issue is when I get into the part of the site that is driven by our db there are no assemblies available.

I believe I only have the client version of .NET 4 installed and according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153048/missing-referenced-assemblies-folder-for-net-4-0) I should simply need to download and install the full framework.  Since this is our production box I wanted to confirm this.  Also would it matter in choosing the standalone installer or the web install?

EDIT:  I just pulled up the Web Installer on our Server and it shows that .NET 4 is installed.  Any tips on what might be causing my missing assembly reference?

Comment: Please be more specific when describing the problem. Saying "there are no assemblies available" doesn't provide any real information that can be used to help you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ended up just installing VS to the server.  Appeared to be the easiest way to accomplish what I needed and it's working so all is well.

Answer (score 0):

For web applications, you need the full framework,

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17851

Client profile is for WPF/WinForms applications, which should be a common sense now, as .NET 3.5 introduced this years ago,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know what you're bumping into. However it's possible that the .NET Framework isn't registered with IIS. There is a command-line tool that can be used to do this registration.

PLEASE note that this can screw stuff up if you aren't careful. So.. be careful. And don't do this on a server taking live traffic.

http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2006/05/30/ASPNet_5F00_regiis.exe-tool_2C00_-setting-the-default-version-without-forcing-an-upgrade-on-all-sites.aspx

Note that this blog is talking about registering v2.0 compared to v1.1. You're going to want to go into the 4.0 directory to run that version of the utility. For example C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319