# WindowsBase.dll static location

Tags: c#, windows, dll, openxml-sdk, gac

I'm using OpenXML SDK for writing data into excel files. Now, this works well on my development machine.

Last week, we were taking our code to a production server and as expected, it did not have OpenXML DLL's installed. For it to work correctly, I need two DLL's on the server - 1. DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll and 2. Windowsbase.DLL. I created a folder in the C drive and placed these DLL's in it. Let's say I placed them in the folder C:\OpenXML

For some reason, the reference in my solution for DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll is pointing correctly to  C:\OpenXML\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll but WindowsBase is pointing to the location C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\WindowsBase.dll. I checked the location property from my DEV machine. Then I did a quick search for WindowsBase in C drive which brought up a lot of copies of that DLL. So I tried adding them one after another but still WindowsBase kept pointing to C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\WindowsBase.dll. On DEV workstation, it works fine. But, on the server, the location C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\WindowsBase.dll is not present and my solution fails.

Not sure why WindowsBase is pointing only to a static location always. If there is flexibility, I can place it in some folder in server and reference it without any issues (like I did for the other library DocumentFormat.OpenXML.DLL). Any way around this?

Comment: WindowsBase is always installed in the GAC since it is an assembly that's part of the framework.   The one in Reference Assemblies is entirely unusable, it is only meant to compile programs, it does not contain any code.  Why it isn't available on that machine is unguessable, the obvious way ahead is to re/install the framework.

Comment: I never had to deploy "WindowsBase.dll", only "DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll". Did you register it into the GAC ? it should be enough

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My issue was somewhere else. It was to do with the version of DocumentFormat.OpenXML.dll I had loaded. I was trying to use the DLL meant for .NET 3.5 in .NET 4.

My understanding of WindowsBase was wrong initially. C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\ is used by Visual Studio to reference shared libraries. On the server, where there is no Visual Studio, the solution would point to the GAC. So it is enough if the library is present in GAC.

The following extract from Simon's answer at [Missing Referenced Assemblies Folder for .NET 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153048/missing-referenced-assemblies-folder-for-net-4-0) explains this.

> Reference Assemblies folder is used with Visual Studio. While the
>   actual deployed application will use the GAC in
>   c:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Assembly. I am assuming you didn't install
>   Visual Studio on your server, therefore you wouldn't have the
>   Reference Assemblies Folder.

Understanding this helped me solve the issue. Hope this helps someone else.